# how to update data in D3 version 4?

Tags: d3.js

I have the following sample data.

```
var d1 = [11,18,20];
var d2 = [11,11,20];
```

I tried with methods enter() and exit() but update does not work? 
please help me.

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("height","100%")
        .attr("width","100%");

var rect = svg.selectAll("rect");

      rect
      .data(d1)
      .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("height",function(d,i){ return d*15; })
                .attr("width","50")
                .attr("fill","pink")
                .attr("x",function(d,i){ return 100*i; })
                .attr("y",function(d,i){ return 300-(d*15); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update pattern was changed in d3v4. From [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection):

> In addition, `selection.append` no longer merges entering nodes into the
>   update selection; use `selection.merge` to combine enter and update
>   after a data join.

You have to rewrite your code:

```
var rect = rect.selectAll("rect")
  .data(d1)

rect
  .enter().append("rect")
  .merge(rect) // <== !!! doing merge here
  .attr("height",function(d,i){ return d*15; })
  .attr("width","50")
  .attr("fill","pink")
  .attr("x",function(d,i){ return 100*i; })
  .attr("y",function(d,i){ return 300-(d*15); });
```

Comment: This won't work: you're merging an enter selection, which contains the data, with this: `svg.selectAll("rect")`. Follow altocumulus' suggestion above.

Comment: @altocumulus You are right, thanks. I updated the answer.

Comment: My bad guys. Thanks for your help. I have changed it.